# Can't read from paired and connected Bluetooth device

Tags: bluetooth

I'm running a code on Arduino and using Bluefruit EZ-link to pass data from Arduino to Raspberry Pi3B. The Arduino code is working as well as its setup with the EZ Link as we've already got the whole thing running on Windows.

I've already successfully paired and bind serial port named /dev/rfcomm0. Now when I run a simple read code:

```
import serial
ser = serial.Serial('/dev/rfcmm0', 9600)

while True:
    res = ser.read()
    print res
```

I'm seeing that the EZ Link LED is blinking fast, an indicator that it is connected via bluetooth to the Pi. However, I'm not seeing anything printed.

Hope someone point out what am I missing. I've been stuck with this the whole day.